# Using ssh with -t and -f options

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am forwarding ports so that I can connect to a jupyter notebook running on a server only visible to another computer.  I have this working, but I would like to make it so my ssh session is detached from my terminal session which I have achieved in other settings using the -f option.  This is what I currently do:

```
ssh -t user@host1 -L 8008:localhost:8009 'ssh -L 8009:localhost:8008 user@host2'
```

This allows me to connect to connect to the jupyter notebook running on port 8008 on host2 by connecting to localhost:8008 on my local computer.  When I attempt to use the -f option I get the following errors:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

So how do I achieve the effect of having -f while using -t?  Or do I just have to have a terminal session logged in to host2?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

You need to use `-tt` (double `-t`), which will allocate TTY for you even if you detach from your local terminal.